# What is the difference between domElement and pageContext when using them within an spfx react project?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I need to understand the difference between this:

```
this.domElement.getElementsByClassName
```

which references domElement. This is not usable as I get errors saying it doesn't exist on 'myproject'.

I also use this:

```
this.props.context.pageContext.web
```

etc..

What is the difference between the two or are they both different in their usage?

Please note, I understand what domElement is, but how it's used here is not what I understand.

I need to understand because I see a lot of demonstrations of features (which I need to use) that use domElement in their spfx project, although it's not usable by me!

C

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to create a File Upload feature which uploads a doc to a SharePoint list. I'm trying to understand the basics of what the multiple solutions require before trying it myself. I've struggled to use this particular feature so I've decided I need to understand the basics first.

Answer (score 1):

pageContext is built by SharePoint client runtime (JS)libraries, it contains many SharePoint client side objects.

[image]

Stefan Bauer had shared good explanation for domElement below.

https://n8d.at/this-domelement-is-your-new-document-object-in-spfx-web-parts-development/

Update:
In webpart.ts, not in component .tsx.

[image]

Update:

Component property interface.

```
import { WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

export interface IReactSpFxProps {
  description: string,
  context: WebPartContext,
  userToken:string
}
```

.ts

```
const element: React.ReactElement<IReactSpFxProps> = React.createElement(
            ReactSpFx,
          {
            description: this.properties.description,
            context:this.context,
            userToken: accessToken            
          });

        ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
```

.tsx:

```
public componentDidMount() {
    var dom=this.props.context.domElement;
```

Comment: Why does VSC say this.domElement does not exist on 'my project' ?

Comment: Would I simply type this.domElement into the render root or into the const element: React.ReactElement<IJobevalProps> = React.createElement(MyProj, {   here?   } );

Comment: If you need to send to component, send it as prometer as you shared(need define property in your component to accept it).

Comment: Get it from parent context, instead of sending it directly, check my update.